# Linear SVM vs Decision Stumps for AdaBoost

Tags: svm, boosting, adaboost

I have heard that AdaBoost can use a linear SVM as a weak classificer. I wonder why Decision Stumps is often used with AdaBoost? Booth are binary classifiers.

In my opinion, linear SVM seems to be a very good choice because it will return a linear model on the form, for every iteration.

$$y = sign(c*x + b)$$

It'also very easy to evalutate the data and find which data points are missclassified. By using Decision Stumps, it's way much harder to train an AdaBoost model.